# Making a circle bounce with javascript

Tags: javascript

My objective is to make a circle move to the right until it hit the end of the window. Afterwards it should turn left until it hits the left side of the window. I am having a difficult time trying to figure out why my circle won't bounce off once it hits the right side of a window. The Circle does not go the full window width before 'bouncing' off.

Here is the html part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Animate</title>
    <script src="animate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>JavaScript Timers</h2>
    <p>
        <button onclick="left('thingToMove');">&larr; Move Left</button>
        <button onclick="stopMoving();">Stop</button>
        <button onclick="right('thingToMove');">Move Right&rarr;</button>
    </p>
    <div id='thingToMove' style="left:10px; position:absolute;">
        <img src="bluecircle.png" >
    </div>
    <div id="instructions" style="position: relative; top:1.25in;">
        <h3>Instructions</h3>
        <ol>
            <li>Re-write animate.js to use <code>setInterval()</code> instead of <code>setTimeout</code></li>
            <li>Add functionality to "bounce" off the side of the window rather than disappear.<br /><em>hint:</em> <code>window.innerWidth</code></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I have so far for my javascript.

```
var moving = "";
function $(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
function right(id){
        stopMoving();
        $(id).style.left = parseInt($(id).style.left) + 1 + 'px';
        moving = setInterval(function(){right(id);},10);
        alert(window.innerWidth);
        if($(id).style.left > (window.innerWidth) + 'px'){
            left(id);
        }
}

function left(id){ 
        stopMoving();
        $(id).style.left = parseInt($(id).style.left) - 1 + 'px';
        moving = setInterval(function(){left(id);},10);
        if($(id).style.left < 0 + 'px'){
            right(id);
        }
}

function stopMoving(){
        window.clearInterval(moving);
}
```

The circle will usually go about 90px to the right before it bounces back to the left. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing strings for those widths, which means string comparison rules apply:  `'90px' > '100px'` is **TRUE**, because `9` is larger than `1`.

String comparison rules are not "human comparison" rules.